# Why does quantization lead to observed quantites becoming probabilities?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, probability, born-rule

I am reading the nice discussion on this [MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/q/6200/) on the idea behind Quantization mathematically. This [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/6216/159957) is quite nice, and for my question, I take some quotes from it:

> "quantum mathematics" is when you try to take geometric facts, written algebraically, and interpret them in a noncommutative algebra.
> .

.

.

> Then quantization is the process of reversing the above quotient. In particular, lots of spaces that we care about come with canonical Poisson structures. For example, for any manifold, the algebra of functions on its cotangent bundle has a Possion bracket. "Quantizing a manifold" normally means finding a noncommutative algebra so that some quotient (like the one above) gives the original algebra of functions on the cotangent bundle. The standard way to do this is to use Hilbert spaces and bounded operators, as I think another answerer described.

Mathematically speaking, I think I can understand at least some of this, but I am totally confused how it relates to physical fact. By such a procedure as said above, how do classical variables become describe by probability wave functions?

Comment: That vectors in the Hilbert space have an interpretation as probabilities is an experimental fact called the Born rule. It's not something people know how to derive.

Comment: [Why do we use Eigenvalues to represent Observed Values in Quantum Mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/583835/37364)

Comment: I guess I'm seeking something comperative, how did singular values become probabilistic?

Comment: In QM, *everything* is probabilistic: it is the fundamental theory of computing expectation values for observables/operators. A more "intuitive" bridge between classical physics and QM is phase-space or "deformation" QM, on which there are dozens of questions on this site, and articles in Wikipedia, not to mention textbooks.

Comment: Axiomatically. see a version of the postulates of quantum mechanics here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html , particularly the wavefunction postulate.

Comment: maybe my answer here will help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90164/physics-the-why-vs-how-question/90526#90526

Comment: There is a famous saying about quantization due to Edward Nelson: "First quantization is a mystery, but second quantization is a functor!" [cf here](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/categories.html)

Comment: Classical variables are described by operators or deformation quantization equivalents, but *not wavefunctions* that these are acting on...